# Unity C# - Rotating more than one object at a time with quaternions isn't working

Tags: unity-game-engine, rotation, axis, quaternions, angle

I have several cannon objects that need to rotate to point at their targets and fire a cannon ball. As long as only one cannon object is in the scene it works just fine. If I add any additional canons they only aim on the y axis (turning left and right), but they don't rotate to point in the random angle assigned on the x axis (aiming up and down). I don't understand at all why this would happen. Please help? :)

A script is attached to each cannon with that has this piece of code in it. I don't see why it should interfere with other cannon scripts...?

```
private IEnumerator Aim(float durationToRot)
{
    if (rotating)
    {
        yield break;
    }
    rotating = true;

    target = GetLandPoint();
    angle = Random.Range(25, 45);
    Quaternion desiredAngle = Quaternion.Euler(angle, 0, 0);
    Quaternion lookRot = Quaternion.LookRotation(target - transform.position);
    Quaternion lookAngle = Quaternion.Euler(desiredAngle.eulerAngles.x, lookRot.eulerAngles.y, 0);

    turnTime = 0f;
    while (turnTime < durationToRot)
    {
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.rotation, lookAngle, turnTime / durationToRot);
        turnTime += Time.deltaTime;

        yield return null;
    }
    transform.rotation = lookAngle;
    rotating = false;
    FireCannon(target);
}
```

Comment: In general you probably shouldn't be using [`eulerAngles`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion-eulerAngles.html) as `the values you read back out may be quite different from the values you assigned` ... instead of `desiredAngle.eulerAngles.x` why not simply use the `angle`? ^^

Comment: I thought that the angle variable needed to be in Quaternion format instead of a float when I used it in the Slerp function. :P Any Ideas on what to use instead of getting the eulerangles? I need the y axis of the position on the ground to shoot at and the x axis of the angle of the turret and then to Slerp them both in the while loop.

Answer (score 0):

I tried your script and everything is working fine, maybe you made mistake somewhere else, is your cannons child of another cannons, if so, then try to use localRotation instead of rotation.

Comment: Thank you for answering as well. It works for me as well when there is only one object in the scene, but when there's more than one, the cannon doesn't rotate on the x axis. The really odd thing is that the transform info on each of the cannons shows that thet are supposedly rotating, but they don't... I tried using localRotation instead of rotation, but that didn't solve the problem. Any other ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you both for answering, but I found why I was having trouble. A part of my cannon prefab was toggled to "static" somehow... omg.. Still not sure why a single instance of the cannon would work though when multiples of the same object didn't work.. odd.